# Why am I not seeing Numpy's DeprecationWarning?

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I recently updated Python's Numpy package on one of my machines, and apparently I've been relying on [a deprecated feature of numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6464) for a while now:

```
>>> np.__version__
'1.10.4'
>>> a = np.ones(10, dtype=np.uint16)
>>> a /= 0.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'H') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

One of the commenters in the above link pointed out:

> Probably means you didn't see the deprecation warnings since forever
>   ;)

...which is correct, I didn't.

But **why**? How did I manage to miss the deprecation warning?

Consistent with [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufunc), this same code worked differently in my previous numpy version:

```
>>> np.__version__
'1.9.2'
>>> a = np.ones(10, dtype=np.uint16)
>>> a /= 0.5
>>> a
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=uint16)
```

...but **shouldn't this trigger a warning**? Do I misunderstand how numpy handles deprecation warnings? **How can I be sure I'm not missing other deprecation warnings**?

My python environment:

```
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: they're ignored by default

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DeprecationWarnings are [ignored by default](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#default-warning-filters). You need to enable them, either by running Python with the [`-Wd` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W):

```
python -Wd my_source_file.py
```

or by installing a new warning filter specification that overrides the one for ignoring DeprecationWarning:

```
import warnings

# Print any warning the first time a given source line issues them,
# overriding built-in filters that ignore some warning types.
warnings.filterwarnings("default")
```

Comment: Jesus, good to know. Big hole in my education, thanks for fixing it.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for this. wild. btw I think you meant `warnings.filterwarnings` (plural) not `warnings.filterwarning`

Comment: @MaxPower: Whoops! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am runnng python3 --version
Python 3.8.16
Ansible --version
ansible [core 2.13.13]

I haven't able to disply deprecation warnings on my screen. I do have

## to disable these warnings, set the following value to False:

deprecation_warnings=True . This doens't take effect true/false